# I cannot understand Tensorflow system

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I cannot understand Tensorflow system.
First,I wrote

```
#coding:UTF-8

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf

const1 = tf.constant(2)
const2 = tf.constant(3)
add_op = tf.add(const1,const2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(add_op)
    print(result)
```

and it print out 5.
Second,I wrote

```
#coding:UTF-8

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf

const1 = tf.constant(2)
const2 = tf.constant(3)
add_op = tf.add(const1,const2)
print(add_op)
```

and it print out Tensor("Add:0", shape=(), dtype=int32).
I cannot understand this system.
I use Python and other languages, so I think `tf.add()` method is add method.However,in the case of  Tensorflow,it seems different.
why is this part

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(add_op)
    print(result)
```

necessary?
What functions does this part have?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to read the official [Getting Started with TensorFlow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKWOq.png) guide of TensorFlow to get to know the core concepts of the library, such as the one which seems to be the problem here:

Every TensorFlow program consists of two parts:

1. Building the computational graph.
2. Running the computational graph.

Now, what is a "computational graph"? In TensorFlow, you specify a series of operations which are executed on your input. This series of operations is your "computational graph". To understand that, lets look at some examples:

- Simple addition: let's look at your example, your code is

  ```
  const1 = tf.constant(2)
  const2 = tf.constant(3)
  add_op = tf.add(const1,const2)
  ```

  This creates two constant nodes in the graph, and creates a second node which adds them. Graphically, this looks like:

  [image: graph for 2+3]
- To make it a little bit more complex, lets say you have an input `x` and want to add a constant `3` to it. Then your code would be:

  ```
  const1 = tf.constant(2)
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
  add_op = tf.add(const1,x)
  ```

  and your graph is

  [image: graph for x+3]

In both examples, this was the *first part* of the program. So far, we only defined how our computational graph should look, i.e. what inputs we have, what outputs, and all calculations needed.

But: **no calculations have been done so far!** In the second example, you don't even know what your input `x` is - only that it will be a `float32`.
If you have a GPU, you'll notice that TensorFlow hasn't even touched the GPU yet. Even if you have a huge neural network with millions of training images, this step runs in milliseconds, as no "real" work has to be done.

Now comes part two: *running* the graph we defined above. Here's where the work happens! 
We fire up TensorFlow by creating a `tf.Session`, and then we can *run* anything by calling `sess.run()`.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(add_op)
    print(result)
```

In the second example, we now have to tell TensorFlow what our value `x` should be:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(add_op, {x: 5.0})
    print(result)
```

**tl;dr:** every TensorFlow program has two parts: 1. building a computational graph, and 2. running this graph. With `tf.add` you only define the graph, but no addition is performed yet. To run this graph, use `sess.run()` as in your first piece code.

Comment: thx!!ur answer is very good for me, it can be understandable very well.I have a questions, can I call tf.Session method is activation function?I read Tensorflow tutorial, but I cannot understand this part well.

Comment: Good explanation, especially for beginners.